# How to run a Gradle subproject task from another Gradle subproject via GradleBuild task type

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a Gradle project with the next structure:

```
prj
+---subprj1
|   \---build.gradle
+---subprj2
|   \---build.gradle
\---build.gradle
```

*subprj1/build.gradle* contents are:

```
task caller (type: GradleBuild) {
    setTasks(["subprj2:callee"])
}
```

and *subprj2/build.gradle* contents are:

```
task callee {
    println "Has been called."
}
```

This way it doesn't work. 
Is it possible to use `setTasks` & `GradleBuild` task type at this case?
How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should call `callee` just before `caller`

```
task caller (dependsOn: [':subprj2:callee']) {

}
```

or:

```
task caller {
  dependsOn ':subprj2:callee'
}
```

or:

```
caller.dependsOn ':subprj2:callee'
```